# Using parameters to execute delete statement in vba ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want the below Delete statement to be executed when the user click the delete button.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete from [TableName] where ColumnName is not null"
```

But I want the user to input the tablename and the columnName. Can you please help

Comment: Do you want to prompt them or take the value from a field on the form? Read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa160564(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: I want a pop up message with a drop down list

Comment: Use a combo box control. Are you wanting the list for the tables to choose from?

Comment: Yes correct. A list of table names in the drop down

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: The answer was edited to include a link to a tutorial on how to get all table names into combo box. (If you find my answer helpful, please vote up; if you find it is the answer, please mark it as such.)

Comment: I would caution you on implementing this. Do not leave it to users to run large scale DML commands especially open-ended ones on potentially all tables and all columns. Remember `NULL` can sometimes mean something in columns.

Answer (score 0):

This will grab **parameter from form control**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Country = _
  [Forms]![frmSelectCountry]![txtCountry]
```

This will **prompt user "Enter County"**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Country = _
  [Enter Country]
```

To **prompt a user for the table name** and prompt user to "Enter County":

```
tblName= InputBox("Please enter a name for the source table", "?")

mysql = "DELETE * FROM " & tblName _
           & "WHERE (((" & tblName & ".[City])=[Enter City]));"
```

You could build a form (named "frmSelectTable") with a combo box control (named "cboTable") on it listing the tables to choose from and have the code retrieve the combo box controls value.

```
tblName = [Forms]![frmSelectTable]![cboTable]
```

*Incorporate with your work*:

```
tblName = InputBox("Please enter a name for the source table", "?")
mysql = "DELETE * FROM " & tblName _
           & "WHERE ColumnName Is Not Null;"
CurrentDb.Execute mysql
```

Here is a tutorial that will walk you through making the form that has a combo box listing all the tables in your database:
[How to Get all Table Names into Combo box](http://www.iaccessworld.com/get-table-name-combo-box/)