# SQL Query to Filter Multiple Criteria in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I'm at a point where I just need to build a SQL Query String that would let me filter data depending on three textboxes.

First Textbox the user enters Invoice number so if that textbox is not null then the query should use that to filter.

The other two textboxes is Date and Place. These two goes together so it would be something like if Date and Place Textboxes is not null then filter by date and place.

This is what I have now:

```
 SELECT tbl1Facturas.Verificado, tbl1Facturas.Factura, tbl1Facturas.Fecha, tbl5Localidades.NombreLocalidad, tbl6Suplidores.NombreSuplidor, tbl1Facturas.Subtotal, tbl1Facturas.[IVU MUNICIPAL], tbl1Facturas.[IVU ESTATAL], tbl1Facturas.[Total de Compra], tbl1Facturas.[Exento al IVU ESTATAL], tbl1Facturas.[Credito al Subtotal], tbl1Facturas.[Credito IVU Municipal], tbl1Facturas.[Credito IVU ESTATAL], tbl1Facturas.[Metodo de Pago], tbl1Facturas.[ID Metodo Pago], tbl1Facturas.MetodoPago_PDF, tbl1Facturas.Factura_PDF
 FROM (tbl1Facturas INNER JOIN tbl5Localidades ON tbl1Facturas.Localidad_ID = tbl5Localidades.ID) INNER JOIN tbl6Suplidores ON tbl1Facturas.Suplidor_ID = tbl6Suplidores.ID
 WHERE tbl1Facturas.Factura = '" & Nz(Me.Text16) & "' 
 ORDER BY tbl1Facturas.Fecha;"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what's wrong with your current sql query?

Comment: If this is related to previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200046/ms-access-dao-connection-discard-changes-on-exit) do be aware DAO supports [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao). And especially needed if receiving user input and connecting to a server database: MySQL.

Comment: Look here for an idea...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821503/using-parameters-to-execute-delete-statement-in-vba-ms-access/49822128#49822128

Comment: Parfait same project different problem. Right now I'm looking at parameterization see if it works. THanks sunsesurf looking into the post now!

Comment: So I managed. What I did was use three different queries. So when the form loads it uses one query. When the textbox with the invoice number is updated it changes the query and when the other two textboxes are updated it uses another query. Thanks guys!

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 1):

I’ll work with something like this (I’m using inputbox instead of text box for the example you can then adapt it to your needs):

```
Sub test ()

Dim Invoiceno, myDate, myPlace
Dim SQLString As String

Invoiceno = InputBox(“Enter Invoice Number”)
MyDate = InputBox(“Enter Date”) ‘here you can add a Date Picker 

MyPlace = InputBox(“Enter Place”)

If not Invoiceno is nothing then 

SQLString = ‘here your SQL string to search by invoice number’

Else:

SQLString = ‘here your SQL string to search by Date & Place’

End If

CurrentDb.Execute SQL String

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @IRENE G thank you! Yeah I ended up doing something similar but used the on update events in ms access to trigger the different SQL strings. Got any ideas for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55209990/save-dao-querydef-to-temporary-query-and-output-results-to-excel